# Join and reshape two ndarrays

Tags: python

Here's a working example of what I want by combining two arrays `a` and `b` to make array `c`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]])
b = -a
c = np.reshape(np.array(zip(np.ravel(a), np.ravel(b))), (4,3,2))
```

---

```
print "a = \n", a, "\n"
print "b = \n", b, "\n"
print "c = \n", c
```

Running this shows the result array `c` I'd like:

[image: array results]

I have to imagine there is a more slick way of achieving this.  Is there a more Pythonic way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function dstack from numpy to achieve what you want:

```
 np.dstack((a,b)).reshape((4,3,2))
```

Hope it helps!